# How to change some text by css

Tags: css

I want change text 'week' to 'day' by css.
by number (36) is variable don't hide , don't change .

```
<span class="value">36 week</span>
```

Can I do ?

Comment: Do you need to show  "Week" all the time? Or do you need to show "Week" sometimes and "Day" other times based on some variable?

Comment: I want to build a house.  I could use bricks but instead I will insist on using paper.....

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna do this thing. you can use content property but for that you should have to allow parent div another class with after pseudo-class.

```
<span class="value day">36 </span>
<span class="value week">36 </span>
.day:after{
    content:"day";
}
.week:after{
    content:"week";
}
```

This above way you will get same result as below example

```
<span class="value day">36 day</span>
<span class="value week">36 week</span>
```

Comment: But you would need to manually select if it's `day` or `week` class, so the OP might as well just type the value in directly. This method, whilst correct, doesn't save anything.